# Python: Checking matching values in a text file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file that consists of multiple lines. Each line has multiple values of strings and integers.
Example of text is as follows:

```
>|P1|Pa|,1,2,7,4
>|P2|Pa|,7,9,0,3
>|Pa|P1|,5,5,7,2
>|Pa|P2|,2,3,8,4
>|Pb|Pa|,8,4,3,1
```

The values between the vertical bars , such as P1 and Pa,are identifier for each line.
I want to write a code that recogizes mutual lines with same identifiers and assign the same number to them. So the first and third lines should have last value of 1. The output of the program should be as follows:

```
>|P1|Pa|,1,2,7,4,1
>|P2|Pa|,7,9,0,3,2
>|Pa|P1|,5,5,7,2,1
>|Pa|P2|,2,3,8,4,2
>|Pb|Pa|,8,4,3,1,3
```

To solve this, I created a dictionary to have identifiers as keys and assigned numbers as values. However, I could not assign numbers correctly to mutual lines. The following code:

```
import sys

h=(sys.argv[1])
q_d={}
count=0
with open(h)as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
        count=count+1
        line=line.strip('\n')
        ID=line.split('|')
        q=ID[1]
        s=ID[2]
        q_d[str(q)]=count
        if q_d.has_key(q):
            print line+','+str(q_d[q])
        elif q_d.has_key(s):
            print line+','+str(q_d[s])
```

And here is the output I get:

```
>|P1|Pa|,1,2,7,4,1
>|P2|Pa|,7,9,0,3,2
>|Pa|P1|,5,5,7,2,3
>|Pa|P2|,2,3,8,4,4
```

How to assign same number to mutual lines into the dictionary?

Comment: Instead of using `elif` use `and` in one `if` statement. Or as qwr suggests, make the key a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set, which is order independent. Psuedo-code:

```
q_d = set()
...
if (q, s) in q_d:
    ...
else:
    q_d.add((q, s))
```